# Adding a button to a popup content in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a button to a popup content and then control the button elsewhere but the button seems to not function properly. The function of the button works fine without binding it with the button.

```
var popupContent = "<br><button class='btn' id='btn_del' type='submit'>del</button>";
$("#btn_del").click(function() {
    console.log("test");
    layer.setStyle(test);
})
```

Comment: what is `console.log(layer, test)` - any of these undefined?

Comment: `$("#btn_del")` will not find any button until it acctually exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your event-binding to this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btn_del", function() {
  console.log("test");
  layer.setStyle(test);
});
```

Example:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  $('body').append('<button class="btn">Add another button!</button><br/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Add another button!</button><br/>
```

This is useful for binding events to elements that does not yet exist in the DOM, but will exist at some given point.

Comment: Thanks, the solution given by @Arg0n works perfectly.